# When changing my FEP should I pierce it first or just screw the screws through it?

Tags: resin, desktop-printer, sla, maintenance

I'm going to do my first FEP change on my Elegoo Saturn. The manufacturer has a video on changing it that shows them putting the FEP into the gasket frame and then simply screwing the screws right through it.

People on Youtube have videos showing them using a sharp object to piece the film before putting the screws in.

Which is least likely to cause a failure?

Comment: What they do exactly as different? Did they cut the film in pieces, what do you mean? Simply screwing the film after stretching it carefully will be enough. I did it before many times.

Comment: As I said. The manufacturer shows them putting the FEP in the frame and then screwing the screws right through the film. But there are videos of users using a sharp object to make a hole for the screw to go through first. Like using a bradel or a craft knife to make a hole for the screw to go through.

Comment: Now ok, you mean making holes before screwing. So its making puncture. And yes making puncture is needed before screwing. Here is an example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLi3chV43LQ

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it doesn't matter. But it's probably a lot easier if you use a bradel (awl) to pre puncture the holes.

Comment: It makes sense to use any pointed item to puncture the FEP in order to ensure that the hole is placed where it is desired. Using brute force to push a screw through the film does not ensure that it will be well centered or well placed.

Comment: A pointed tip soldering iron may be handy too. When using heat it reduces the chance of tearing the film.